# Facing Issue in integration of POS

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet, consensus, babe, pos

I'm integrating the POS in freshly node template. I'm facing this error: [image]

This is the code repository: https://github.com/Aideepakchaudhary/POA-to-POS

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a dependency problem of sp-consensus.
Solved now!